# Filtering belongsToMany records based on "current" value from child table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, yajra-datatable

I'm building a Laravel application with `yajra/laravel-datatables` in which I try to filter records in a many-to-many relation. I have 3 models involved in this - Unit, Ownership, Contact:

**Unit**

- id
- ...

**Ownership**

- id
- contact_id
- unit_id
- date_from
- date_to

**Contact**

- id
- ...

My goal is to be able to filter units by the name of the current owner. Each unit has multiple owners assigned to it which have a start date (date_from) and end date (date_to).

**Unit Model**

```
public function ownerships() {
    return $this->hasMany(Ownership::class);
}

// I also tried something like this
// Datatable ignores it though and fetches all ownerships
public function current_ownership() {
    return $this->hasOne(Ownership::class)->latest('date_from')->limit(1);
}
```

**Ownership Model**

```
public function contact() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class);
}

public function unit() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Unit::class);
}
```

I have also tried using belongsToMany on my unit model like so. However, that did not get me anywhere either.

```
public function owners() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Contact::class, 'ownerships', 'unit_id', 'contact_id')
        ->using(Ownership::class)
        ->withPivot('date_from', 'date_to');
}
```

Right now my UnitDataTable data table is set up as follows.

```
public function query(Unit $model) {
    return $model->with([
        'ownerships.contact',
        'tenancies.contact',
    ])
    ->select('units.*')
    ->where('house_id', $this->house_id)
    ->newQuery();
}

// Excerpt of actual full getColumns()
protected function getColumns() {
    return [
        Column::make('ownerships')
            ->name('ownerships.contact.last_name')
            ->title('Owner'),
    ];
}
```

So far the datatable works without errors. However, searching for a name also returns names that are not the owner anymore but exist in the history of owners of a unit. I can't seem to figure out, how to limit my name search to just the latest / current owner.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public function query(Unit $model)
{
return $model->with([
        'ownerships.contact',
        'tenancies.contact',
    ])
    ->filterColumn('ownerships', function ($query, $keyword) {
       $query->whereHas('ownerships.contact', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
          $q->where('last_name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
      });
    })
    ->select('units.*')
    ->where('house_id', $this->house_id)
    ->newQuery();
}

// Excerpt of actual full getColumns()
protected function getColumns()
{
    return [
        Column::make('ownerships')
              ->name('ownerships.contact.last_name')
              ->title('Owner'),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't look like it could work to me, since filterColumn is a method of yajra/laravel-datatables and therefore not available in Eloquent\Builder. I tried it and it resulted in "call to undefined method"